# JQUERY accordions are jumpy/snappy

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/mickzer/3MbRJ/1/

Above is a fiddle of a set of accordions.

When you click the accordions to open and close them, the transition is very snappy and almost jumpy.

Here is the JQUERY:

```
$('#accordion .hide').hide();
    $('#accordion .title .anchor').click(function(){

        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
        return false;

    });

    $('#accordion .title span:last').click(function () {

        $('#accordion .hide').slideUp();

    });
```

Why is this and how do I stop it happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.hide` has `min-height: 70px` set. Take this out, and your snappiness goes away. The reason this is causing issues is when it goes from `display: none` to `display: block`, it immediately has a height of 70px.